# Threads vs TPL vs Async Delegates in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, io, delegates, task-parallel-library, datareader

I have an application that is working well in production, but I wonder if I could have implemented the concurrency better....

ASP.NET .NET 4, C#

Basically, it generates n number of sql statements on the fly (approx 50 at the moment) and then runs them concurrently and writes the data to .csv files.

EDIT: First I create a thread to do all the work on so the page request can return. Then on that thread...

For each of the SQL statements I create a new Task using the TPL and execute it using a datareader and write the data to disk. When the last file is created I write some summary data to a summary file and zip it all up and give it to the user.

Should I have used Threads or Asynchronous Delegates instead?

I haven't posted code as I am really just wondering if my overall approach (i.e. TPL) is the best option in this situation.

Please don't lecture me about creating dynamic sql, it is totally necessary due to the technicalities of the database I am reading from and not relevant to the question. (Its the back end of a proprietary system. Got 7 thousand+ tables).

Comment: Make sure you get the difference between async and multithreading/multitasking before you do any changes in your code. They are not the same, and you should probably combine both in your scenario.

Comment: Doing `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` in ASP.NET is really a bad idea. The HTTP request will not be completed until all tasks have been completed. You're really only hurting the web app scalability with this. Use [async SqlDataReader API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/07/15/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta-part-2-examples.aspx) instead.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I think I understand the difference between the 2 concepts. :) Could you elaborate? Benefits? So maybe call some async method on the datareader (didnt check if there was one)?  When I mentioned Async Delegates I was thinking maybe I should have done it as a bunch of async callbacks, one for each sql query/write and when finished it does the zipping....

Comment: @Noseratio Thanks, but I have taken that into account. When the user clicks the button I create a separate thread for all this stuff and then returns, and then on that thread it creates all the read/write threads. This means that the request returns straight away. The page then uses a timer in an update panel to poll for completion of the whole operation.

Comment: @Noseratio: Also, re: async SqlDataReader API, we are on .net 4 not 4.5. Dont think that is available. Also, I am using ODBC because I hit both Oracle and SQL Server and it was a bit easier to implement with the System.Data.Odbc.

Comment: @user2416689, cross-request threads inside ASP.NET are not a good idea either, it's been discussed here on SO many times. You should be running a Windows service for this and communicate to it. Or a WCF service on a separate host.

Comment: @Noserati, Can you explain further or provide some links? I cant find anything under "cross-request thread". I take it it is bad to have a thread hanging around for a long time. Will this take away threads from all the apppools on the server or just the one my app is running under?

Comment: @user2416689, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/990986/1768303) and [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/why-not-use-polling-threads).

Comment: @Noseratio: I was talking about a ASP.NET AJAX timer (ends up being javascript) that makes an ajax request every few seconds to see if the zip file is there. So no idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I have used Threads or Asynchronous Delegates instead?

Apparently, your background thread operation spans across the boundaries of a single HTTP request. In this case, it doesn't really matter what API you use to run such operation: `Task.Run`, `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`, `new Thread` or anything else.

You shouldn't be running a lengthy background thread operation, which lifetime spans multiple HTTP requests, inside ASP.NET address space. While it's relatively easy to implement, this approach may have issues with IIS maintainability, scalability and security. Create a WCF service for that and call it from your ASP.NET page:

[How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If we start a new thread in ASP.Net from the thread which is serving the http request, and new thread has an unhandled exception, the worker process will crash immediately. Even if we use WCF service and call that from ASP.Net the ASP.Net thread is going to wait for the result. So better use any queuing mechanism so that the requests is in queue and queue can process in a different time based on the processing capacity. Of course when we say queuing we need to think about queue failure, requeue etc...But its worth if the application is big and needs to scale.