# Triggering an async operation in from mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

Here is my scenario.

I want to create a web endpoint that will kick off a service that may be long-running, perhaps 20-30 minutes. I'd like to return an HttpResponseResult immediately and trigger the service to run asynchronously, instead of having to wait for the service to complete before returning a response to client.

What is the easiest way to go about doing this?  I don't need to return any sort of result from the service, just trigger it.

Comment: Don't run zombie threads inside IIS address space: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21873422/1768303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run a task using `Task.Run(() => <trigger service call> )` and ignore the return value. The only down side of this is that it will consume a thread from the thread pool. If the service has an asynchronous version of the operation you are calling you can use a `TaskCompletionSource`

Answer (score 0):

`SignalR` will be my choice to do this kind of behavior. Tutorial is [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr).

Basically, a client invokes a server method/action and is 'done' (you can continue and do whatever y you want in the client side). Once the server is done it pushes data/notification to client via RPC.

On the server side you can execute the code anyway you like, synchronously or async.

Comment: Wouldn't there be an easier way by just created an async method that I can call. The part I am confused about is how to implement an async method when I am completely unconcerned with the result from the aysnc process.